# Overlay video over an image with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, blend

I want to overlay semi-transparent video over the image with blend filter. However when I use blend=all_mode='addition' video becomes pink. Here is the command, how can I improve it?

```
ffmpeg -i overlay_video.mp4 -i background_image.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setdar=dar=16/9,scale=1280:720,format=rgba[vid];[1:v]setdar=dar=16/9,scale=1280:720[img];[img][vid]blend=all_mode='addition':all_opacity=1,format=yuv420p10le" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -b:a 256k -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

Comment: Why don't you use the overlay filter?

Comment: I just edited the title, I though the video was semi-transparent but actually it's black and that's why it does not work with overlay. So I use a blend filter and all this stuff to remove black color from video.

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38581696/5726027) method.

Comment: @Mulvya Feel free to copy that answer (or the essential parts needed) here, or point me to a duplicate on SU so we can close it.